# Are there any automatic pattern recognition algorithm for integer series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, references

I am looking for an algorithm, that given an input such as 1, 2, 3, 4... would output either " f(x_n) = n " or at least continue the series and give a "5". I know this can be done for simple pattern by simple extrapolation but what about harder pattern ?

I know that Difference Tables works for polynomials series but I am looking for an algorithm which works for all integers series such as Fibonacci sequence for example or more complex sequence such as "1, 2 , 10, 12, 3, 4, 13, 14, ....".

I am not sure such an algorithm exist but I haven't found anything by googling and would like to know about any previous or unsuccessful attempts.

What kind of methods can be used to solve them ?
What if we have an arbitrary large input sequence ?

Please give me references about previous work on this problem or keywords to make research on this subject myself.

Thank you

Comment: hardly an algorithm, but if you're just looking for a practical solution: https://oeis.org/

Comment: What happens if 2 (or more) distinct sequences have the first $k$ terms in common, but differ for (at least) the $k+1$th term? How should a model deal with that situation?

Comment: There is, for positive integer series: it's called the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In general it's difficult to find patterns in a complex sequence.

But for simple sequences like Fibonacci for which there is a linear recurrence relation involving past few terms (e.g., $f_{n}=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$), a simple linear model could be used (off course we need to know how many previous terms we need to predict the next term, e.g., for Fibonacci we need last 2 terms, for Tribonacci last 3 terms etc.), as shown in the following `R` code:

```
S <- c(1, 1,  2,  3,  5,  8,  13, 21, 34, 55, 89) # Fibonacci
df <- NULL
for (i in 1:(len(S)-2) {
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x1=S[i], x2=S[i+1], y=S[i+2])) 
}
    
m <- lm(y~., df)
m$coefficients
# (Intercept)           x1           x2 
# 9.473903e-15 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 
predict(m, newdata=data.frame(x1=55, x2=89))
# 144
```

We can see that the linear model could discover the recurrence relation $x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$ and predict the next Fibonacci number in the sequence, given past two Fibonacci number correctly.

We can use time series to find seasonality / trend using models like ARIMA, for example to predict sequences as "1, 2 , 10, 12, 3, 4, 13, 14, ....", using the following `R` code:

```
library(forecast)
S <- c(1, 2 , 10, 12, 3, 4, 13, 14, 5, 6, 15, 16, 7, 8, 17, 18, 9, 10, 19, 20)
model1=auto.arima(ts(S, frequency=8)) # grouped 8 observations together to find pattern, to find MA / AR parameters
forecast(model1,8) # predict next 8 numbers in the sequence given the data
#  Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
#  11.08333 10.71331 11.45336 10.51743 11.64924
#  12.08333 11.71331 12.45336 11.51743 12.64924
#  21.08333 20.71331 21.45336 20.51743 21.64924
#  22.08333 21.71331 22.45336 21.51743 22.64924
#  13.08333 12.71331 13.45336 12.51743 13.64924
#  14.08333 13.71331 14.45336 13.51743 14.64924
#  23.08333 22.71331 23.45336 22.51743 23.64924
#  24.08333 23.71331 24.45336 23.51743 24.64924    
plot(forecast(model1,24))
```

[image]

Notice from above that it could predict the next 8 numbers 11, 12, 21, 22, 13, 14, 23, 24 correctly, given the past numbers in the sequence.

Finally, we could use recurrent neural networks (e.g., LSTMs) for sequence prediction too. An attempt to predict the above series with LSTM (which gives poor results since we don't have much data, also did not do any preprocessing / scaling etc.) this time with `python`, we can use this model (when trained properly) to predict unseen data too:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM

def create_dataset(dataset, window=1):
   X, y = [], []
   for i in range(len(dataset)-window-1):
      a = dataset[i:(i+window), 0]
      X.append(a)
      y.append(dataset[i + window, 0])
   return np.array(X), np.array(y)

import numpy as np
series = np.array([1, 2 , 10, 12, 3, 4, 13, 14, 5, 6, 15, 16, 7, 8, 
                   17, 18, 9, 10, 19, 20, 11, 12, 21, 22, 13, 14, 23, 
                   24, 15, 16, 25, 26], dtype=float)
series = series.reshape(-1, 1)
window = 4
X, y = create_dataset(series, window)
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, batch_size=4, verbose=2)
# predict
pred = model.predict(series)
plt.plot(series)
plt.plot(pred)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the bit about ARIMA. However the rest doesn't really answer the question in the sense that there are no automatic step, at least for the fibonacci part where a human coded a pattern and then the computer fit the data to the pattern and predict the next number of the sequence. What I'm looking for is a way for a program to find itself the pattern from an unknown series or at least, to see if the series fit a pattern known by the computer from others series. The problem with your strategy is that a human would have to enter by hand a lot of strategies to get the right answer often.

Comment: With ARIMA / SARIMA / GARCH or some other time series models and also with RNN (which will need more data to train / learn the parameters), it can be automated to some extent I guess (only thing we need to know perhaps is how many past datapoints we need to predict the next datapoint, since RNNs tend to forget long sequences due to vanishing gradient etc.)

Comment: I didn't knew about ARIMA so I will do research about it. I just tried it on the first 24 prime numbers and it didn't gave good result so I will try to understand what kind of patterns it can fit or not. Anyways, thanks for your help, I will also try to look capabilities of RNN or LSTM for this problem.

Comment: Predicting / finding patterns in Primes with a model? are you serious? Given that PRIMES is in P was proved formally only a few years ago? Do we have that much understanding for primes? is not it too high to expect a machine would find pattern in primes just by itself just looking at a few example prime numbers?

Comment: Starting thinking about this, my hope was to find a program that would be roughly equivalent to a human in solving this kind of patterns and primes didn't seems too much to ask. Given the lack of sources, you are probably right that it's maybe a bit too much to ask and no one has put much thought into this or has result to show for it. A simple query to the OEIS database is probably the best that can be done for now.